# Bash interprets too long arguments for an option

Tags: bash, getopts

I'm writing a bash script, that can take three options: c, p, and m; c can't have arguments, but p and m must have arguments. In my script I have these lines of code:

```
while getopts ":cp:m:" opt
do
   case $opt in
      c  ) capitals=1
           ;;
      m  ) length=$OPTARG
           ;;
      p  ) number=$OPTARG
           ;;
      \? ) echo "ERROR" 1>&2
           exit 1
           ;;
   esac
done
shift `expr $OPTIND - 1`
```

Now, when I write in the command line

```
myScript.sh -c -p 15 -m 12
```

all goes perfect. But when I write

```
myScript.sh -cp15m12
```

it goes wrong. Bash interprets the argument of the option `'p'` as `"15m12"`, while it should just be `"15"`.
How can I solve this?

Comment: But why are you stripping spaced from command line?

Comment: The `p` option has absolutely no way to tell whether the `m12` part of the string goes with the `p` option or is a separate option on it's own. This would be true for any command with these kinds of options unless you write your own option parser to separate the argument for numbers versus letters, etc.

Comment: It's probably better to use `shift $(($OPTIND - 1))` than to use `expr`.

Answer (score 3):

Since command-line arguments are not typed, there is no way to tell `bash` that the argument to `-p` must be an integer, and therefore no way for `bash` to infer that the correct way to parse `-cp15m12` is as `-c -p15 -m12` rather than as `-c -p15m12`. Since `-c` does *not* take an argument and `getopts` cannot define multi-character options, `bash` *can* infer that `-cp15` is split into two separate options, `-c` and `-p`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `getopts` is fairly limited -- it's not hard to write your own replacement which supports option clustering.  Here's a quick ad-hoc attempt.

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
    case $1 in
     -*) opt=${1#-}; shift;;
     *) break;;
    esac
    while [ "$opt" ]; do
        case $opt in
          '-') opt=""; break 2;; 
          c*)  capitals=1; opt=${opt#c};;
          m[0-9]*)
            opt=${opt#m}; length=${opt%%[!0-9]*}; opt=${opt#$length};;
          m) opt=""; length=$1; shift;;
          p[0-9]*)
            opt=${opt#p}; number=${opt%%[!0-9]*}; opt=${opt#$number};;
          p) opt=""; number=$1; shift;;
      h|\?) echo "Syntax: $0 [-c] [-m length] [-p number]" >&2; exit 1;;
          *) echo "Invalid option '$opt'" >&2; exit 2;;
        esac
    done
done

cat <<HERE
capitals: '$capitals'
length: '$length'
number: '$number'
args: '$@'
HERE
```

(Not sure if `break 2` is entirely compatible with stock `sh`.  Works for me on `dash`.)